# command prompt opens and closes while startup in windows 8.1

Tags: command-line

Command prompt opens and closes while startup? Two days before I tried to install java application but because of problem in installation i cancelled the installation and removed it's setup. After that moment command prompt opens and closes whenever i login my PC. My antivirus has expired 15 days before. Help me please. Why this is happening and how to get rid of it

Comment: Get a new license for your antivirus? On a more serious note, did you check all the locations Windows has for automatically starting stuff? E.g. start menu, Run section of the registry?

Comment: Behavior like this normally indicates there is a rogue entry in the registry that starts it. There are dozens of good free security suites out there.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the installer left some garbage behind that now tries to start *something* at startup.

To find out what *something* is, you can use a tool such as [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), and look at the *Logon* tab. If you see something that looks related to the application you tried to install, disable it by unchecking the checkbox in front of it. Reboot and see if the command prompt has disappeared. If it did, it is safe to also delete the entry.